# Orientation problems with launch image in universal app

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have a Universal app with launch screens for iPhone and iPad, following Apple's [naming convention for launch screens](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1588/_index.html).

The app is only for Landscape orientation. When I run it on iPhone, the splash screen (which is 320 × 480 pixels) is rotated 90 degrees **to the RIGHT**, regardless of orientation.

Xcode won't let me rename the launch image to `Default-LandscapeLeft.png` as it's a Universal app. What can I do to correctly display the launch image?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can provide two images, a Default.png for iPhone and Default-LandscapeLeft.png for iPad

Comment: I did that. Like I said, I followed [Apple's naming convention for launch screens](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1588/_index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have portrait orientations disabled in the project settings?

Comment: Yes, portait orientations are disabled in project settings. It's a landscape-only app.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing this by flipping the `UIImageView`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImage *iphoneLaunchImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default"];    
    initialImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:iphoneLaunchImage];

    //Flip it:
    initialImage.transform =  CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1);

    [self.view addSubview:initialImage];
```